# Where do I start on fixing my messy topology?

Tags: topology, subdivision-surface

So I am new to subsurf modeling and I have spent the last week or so working on this model pack. I am pretty happy with where I got so far, and was able to make all my models with quads only (EDIT: I noticed the middle section is a giant n-gon, I fixed that right after posting). The problem I'm having now, is that my topology seems bad. I have read that models should subdivide evenly, and mine does not. Apparently it's also necessary to have square quads. I don't think there is any other way to model this, all my supporting edges are necessary. The bottom picture is my model with 3 levels of subdivision and as you can see, it's not even. Getting decent reflections when subdivided is nearly impossible. I should also mention that the outlets and the plate are separate objects, I just joined them to show my topology. How far off am I from an acceptable topology that  can be distributed and what can I do to fix it?

[image: Topology]

[image: Wireframe]

Comment: You might find this useful: http://topologyguides.com/

Comment: If you gonna follow any topology guides, please start with quality content here: [Polycount Subdiv Modeling](http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Subdivision_Surface_Modeling). Some posts in topologyguides.com are misleading and complete garbage, [like this one](http://topologyguides.com/post/163679954765/loop-reduction).

Comment: I have viewed many topology guides, and while they helped me with specific problems, they don't provide examples of complex objects. All I want to know is if this is a decent topology or not

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny could you explain why reduction loops are garbage?

Comment: @LukeD they are not. But those examples are not good ways to reduce loops. They produce bad surface deformations. They would work only on flat surface where you can do anything. There are less complicated ways to do loop stepping with less surface deformation: [4point triangle row](http://wiki.polycount.com/w/images/f/f4/Santos_Polygon-Table_v04.png)

Comment: Why are you aiming to subdivide it evenly? Are you planning to deform it for an animation? Otherwise, using less edgeloops may help in keeping the model tidy.

Comment: @Carlo It's an object intended to be used in architectural renders. I plan on releasing this as part of a model pack, but I'm just not sure if this topology would keep people from wanting to download it. I'm new to this.

Comment: @jkofskie You can fix the messiness and uneveness of the topology. The object is symmetrical but the topology isn't. You can compare [with this](https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2014/07/08__01_43_27/L.jpg51b97c81-3a04-43b8-bce3-5f051aaa8d44Original.jpg) how clean that is. However that example is not for subdiv, it has only beveled edges, which is good for architecture rending, but bad if you need to do closeups.